# angular $http.get returns empty data when api sends huge data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

My api controller looks like:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public DataTable Get()
{
   DataTable t = new DataTable("t");
   using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {                    
     adapter.Fill(t);                 
   }
  return t;
}
```

And my angular api service requests data from the api:

```
// contoller
$scope.getReport = function () {
        apiService.post('/api/test/get', null,
        getReportLoadCompleted,
        getReportLoadFailed);
}

 function getReportLoadCompleted(result) {
        $scope.report = result.data;
}

// api service
 function post(url, data, success, failure) {
        return $http.post(url, data)
                .then(function (result) {
                    success(result);
                }, function (error) {
                    if (error.status == '401') {

                        $rootScope.previousState = $location.path();
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                    else if (failure != null) {
                        failure(error);
                    }
                });
    }
```

When api returns data within 60 columns and 200.000 rows, it'ok, no failure, result.data is array of 200.000 row. 
But when api return data within 60 columns and 250.000 rows, it's ok but
result.data is empty string.

What is the problem?
Any idea about this?

Comment: WebApi does't have a default serializer for DataTable, you should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571927/net-webapi-datatable

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your end-point app.config. for example;

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```